# Float left not applying?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to float my image to the left? Can't figure out why?

I've applied a class of `align-left` which contains `float: left`.

Live version at - https://www.workbooks.com/salesforce-alternative (see the review grid half way down below the heading 'High customer satisfaction ratings').

**Code:**

```
<section class="bluesection card__content__headings">
    <img alt="Reviews-6.png" class="align-left" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="395" src="/sites/default/files/2017-03/Reviews-6.png" width="400" />
    <h2 style="height: 400px;"></h2>
    <p></p>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.align-left {
    float: left;
}

.bluesection {
    background-color:#ecf0f2;
    padding: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
}
```

Comment: image is already floating to the left, that's why heading **High Customer Satisfaction Ratings** in on the right.

Comment: `float-left` is invalid CSS, you should apply `float: left` instead

Comment: Your example code won't show much because you have no text in your `h2` or `p`. I'm not going to go to some random website to fix your problem; please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<section class="bluesection card__content__headings">
    <h2 class="heading--two inline-block__heading" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px; text-align:center;">High customer satisfaction ratings</h2>
    <img alt="Reviews-6.png" class="align-left" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" src="/sites/default/files/2017-03/Reviews-6.png" width="400" height="395">

    <p class="inline-block__copy">With our world class software, our CRM expertise and proven implementation best practices, we are a genuine partner you can rely on to accompany you on your CRM journey - helping you transform your business and drive ongoing success.</p>

    <p class="inline-block__copy">But don't just take our word for it. Over 268 independent customers have reviewed Workbooks on G2 Crowd where Workbooks consistently scores above Salesforce in satisfaction and richness of functionality.</p>

    <p class="inline-block__copy">The G2 Crowd Report compare Workbooks to its competitors based on independent user reviews. Workbooks is rated higher than Salesforce in most categories.</p>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>
</section>
```

As you can see, I change the `img` after `h2`, and I have added a `p` with `clear:both` style to the end inside of the `section`. Also I have added and removed some CSS styles to get a nice look.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `float-left` but `float: left;`. That's not the only issue though.

The image is already floating left but the reason it doesn't work the way you want it to work is because of the padding of the blue section.

Keep in mind that the image is floating to the left relative to the element it is enclosed in. If you change the value of padding to `padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;` you can see that the image will move further to the left because the padding got smaller than it was initially.

Comment: The main issue is the text is not wrapping around the image which the float should create? If I amend the padding the image moves as you suggest but the text still doesn't wrap?

Comment: @SamJefferies That is because of the height of the `h2` block, which is currently set to 400px. Remove that and text will align.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The image was floated to the left, the reason why the text wasn't wrapping was due to an inline height: 400px being applied to the heading rather than the section.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

it already floated left, the reason it cant go any further is because it reached the edge of the div. padding shrinks the edges relative to the child elements, but maintains it defined size unless values are bigger.

here is a recommended fix:
HTML

```
<section class="bluesection card__content__headings">
  <img alt="Reviews-6.png" class="align-left" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid="" height="395" src="/sites/default/files/2017-03/Reviews-6.png" width="400" />
  <div class="text">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.bluesection {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qf6w18p1/

Answer (score 0):

> I figured it out.
>
> The image was floated to the left, the reason why the text wasn't wrapping was due to an inline height: 400px being applied to the heading rather than the section.

You can fix the height, but when you see your code in a phone device (360px x 640px), the section title `h2` will be located under `img`, and it will not look nice.

My advice is to change the orden of the `h2` and `img` tags.